# Locally Hamiltonian vector fields

Tags: examples-counterexamples, mathematical-physics, differential-forms, vector-fields

Consider the following definitions (taken from [1])

> **Definition.** Let $E$ be a Banach space and $B: E \times E \to \mathbb R$ a continuous bilinear mapping. Then $B$ induces a map $B^\natural: E \to E^*, e \mapsto B^\natural (e)$ defined by $B^\natural(e) \cdot f = B(e,f)$. We call $B$ *weakly nondegenerate* if $B^\natural$ is injective. We call $B$ *(strongly) nondegenerate* if $B^\natural$ is an isomorphism.
>
> **Definition.** Let $(P, \omega)$ be a symplectic manifold. A vector field $X: P \to TP$ is called *Hamiltonian* if there is a $C^1$ function $H: P \to \mathbb R$ such that $i_X \omega = \mbox{d} H$. We say $X$ is *locally Hamiltonian* if $i_X\omega$ is closed.

As a consequence of the Open Mapping Theorem, one can note that $B$ is nondegenerate iff $B$ is weakly nondegenerate and $B^\natural$ is onto. Obviously, the difference between "weakly" and "strongly" vanishes in finite dimensions.

The authors of [1] then note that *if $\omega$ is only weakly nondegenerate, then given a smooth functon $H: P \to \mathbb R$, $X=X_H$ need not exists on all of $P$*. They give no specific examples but remark this is an essential feature in **infinite dimensions**, for the vector fields then correspond to partial differential equations and are only densely defined. Clearly, if $i_X \omega$ is closed, then it is also locally exact thanks to Poincaré Lemma. (at least, in finite dimensions)

**Remark.** Of course, in physics usually the paradigm is reversed: one measures the energy, induces $H$ and tries to construct $X_H$. Nevertheless, in principle one can't be sure $H$ is globally defined, being the passage from the energy to the Hamiltonian the weak link.

Hence my question is: are there finite-dimensional examples, possibly of some physical interest, in which $X_H$ is only locally defined? Does this imply, at least in some cases or as a matter of principle, bearing in mind the infinite-dimensional case too, that one has to use a collection of different Hamiltonians in order to induce the right behaviour? (i.e., to reproduce the right trajectories as integral curves of the locally Hamilontian vector fields?)

---

[1] Abraham, Marsden, Ratiu, *Manifolds, tensor analysis and applications*, chapter 9.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to the first question is

**Counterexample.** Let $\mathbb T^2$ (the 2-torus) endowed with periodic coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$ and with the symplectic form $\Omega = \mbox{d}\theta \wedge \mbox{d}\phi$. Then a costant vector field on $\mathbb T^2$ is locally Hamiltonian but not Hamiltonian (Compare [1], chapter 5). This can be important, e.g, in solid state physics.

For the second question, the answer is in the affermative. See [1] (chapters 5, 6) or [2] (chapter 10). Examples are the magnetic monopole (since $\mathbb R^3 \setminus {0}$ is simply-connected but not contractible) and the steady magnetic field in the $\mathbb R^3 \setminus\{\mbox{$z$-axis}\}$, due to a steady electric current in the $z$-axis.

---

[1] J. Marsden, T. Ratiu *Introduction to mechanics and symmetry*

[2] H. Flanders, *Differential forms with applications to the physical sciences*